# Adding a section bar triggers show of horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, hide

Adding the section in the bottom of the HTML shows a horizontal scrollbar. It is not needed. Changing the width of the scrollbar through the inspector seems to not do anything. Thanks for any help in advance. :)

[HTML](https://gist.github.com/liubomirwm/3d1662b8cef2a6a706e05a6ba06d49ee)

[CSS](https://gist.github.com/liubomirwm/c8b709f7feeeecd3b0ad0eb8ae63256f)

Comment: `overflow: none;` is your friend.

Comment: But when i add overflow-y: hidden to the body the section disappears?